# Era ora che - subjunctive

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I have read the following sentence in an Italian language learning tool:

> Era ora che lui si decidesse.

Why is the subjunctive used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the different uses of [subjunctive](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/uso-congiuntivo), you have:

> Il congiuntivo si usa:
>
> 1) con alcune congiunzioni subordinanti, quali affinché, benché, sebbene, quantunque, a meno che, nel caso che, qualora, prima che, senza che;
>
> 2) con aggettivi o pronomi indefiniti (qualunque, chiunque, qualsiasi, ovunque, dovunque);
>
> ***3) con espressioni impersonali, come è necessario che, è probabile che, è bene che;***
>
> 4) in formule ormai fissate nell'uso (vada come vada; costi quel che costi).

(www.accademiadellacrusca.it)

From *parliamoitaliano.altervista.org*:

> Vanno col [congiuntivo](http://parliamoitaliano.altervista.org/il-congiuntivo-come-e-quando-si-usa/) le forme e le espressioni impersonali. Queste possono essere anche negative (non…):
>
> - È necessario / importante / opportuno / giusto / meglio ecc… che
> - È stupido / scandaloso / divertente / ridicolo / pazzesco / assurdo ecc… che
> - È incredibile / strano / logico / illogico / possibile / impossibile / naturale / innaturale ecc… che
> - È probabile / improbabile / facile / difficile / preferibile / discutibile / plausibile ecc… che
> - ***È ora che… / È  bene che… / È male che…***
> - È un peccato che… / È un assurdo che… / È  uno scandalo che…

Comment: Thanks! It is hard to completely understand how to use the Italian subjunctive mood because it's very hard to find a single (online) source with all its usage rules.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Whole books have been written about the rules of subjunctive, and arguably not even them are exhaustive :)